# How to user author and section in page header

Tags: sectioning

I working on an edition with various author. How can I set the author of the actual essay to the left page header an the title of the actual section to the right pages header?
I tried like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{scrpage2}

%%
% Kopf- und Fußzeile
%%
\clearscrheadfoot
\lehead{\pagemark}
\chead[]{\rightmark}
\rohead{\pagemark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\manualmark

%%
% Titel
%%
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{1\baselineskip}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\orgichapter}{}
\let\orgichapter\chapter
\renewcommand*{\chapter}[1]{%
  \gdef\chapterauthor{#1}% 
  \orgichapter
}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{}


\newlength{\authorindent}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{%
  \ifx\chapterauthor\@empty\else
      \markboth{"Test"}{\chapterauthor}%
      \vskip\baselineskip\nobreak
      \settowidth{\authorindent}{{%
      \usekomafont{sectioning}\usekomafont{chapter}\chapterformat
    }}%
    \noindent\begin{large}\textit{\chapterauthor}\par\nobreak
    \global\let\chapterauthor\@empty \end{large}
 \fi
  \noindent\par\nobreak\vskip 1\baselineskip%
}
\makeatother


%%
% Dokumentenbeginn
%%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Harmann von Aue}[]{Das ist ein Test-Dokument}

\section{Sage es niemand, nur den Weisen}
\blindtext
\Blindtext\Blindtext
\section{Weil die Menge gleich verhöhnt}
\Blindtext


\end{document}
```

The problem seems to be, that \section overrides \marboth. I could use \manualmark in the header but that would have the site effect that sections would not appear in the header at all.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: You might want to have a look at the package `fancyhdr` ...

Comment: I would recommend documentclass memoir for large publications. It has built-in commands for customizing headers (and many other things).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the package fancyhdr

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

Put this after \begin{document}

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}                    % Use fancyhdr
\fancyhead[LE]{\author}       %L for Left, E for Even page
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}    %R for Right  E for Odd page
```

I hope it'll help you !